# How to get data of a table from another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this 2 tables, table1 as the category and table2 as the items in each category, now what i want to do is get the total number of items of table2 where its id is equal to table1.

```
Table1
---------
Cats id = 1
Dogs id = 2
Chickens id = 3

Table2
-------
Mouse hunt = under Cats category (table1)
Mouse hunting = under Cats category (table1)
Dog Whisperer = under Dogs category (table1)
Chicken Pasta = under Chickens category (table1)
Chicken Soup = under Chickens category (table1)
How to make chicken Broth = under Chickens category (table1)
Chicken BBQ = under Chickens category (table1)
```

as per table2 i have 2 items on Cats category, 1 item on DOgs category, 4 under chicken.

when creating those articles/data i usually get table1 ID and store it as invid on table2 so that i can easily fetch and separate the data among other datas.

Now problem is im kind stuck on just getting the total :( here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'connect.php';

if ($_SESSION['userSession']!=1) {
 header("Location: admin.php");
}

$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM table1");
$DBcon->close();

?>

<html>
  <head>
  <title>Categories</title>

  </head>
    <body>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/main.css">
        <div class="main-head" STYLE="FONT-size:20px;text-align: center; padding-top:20px;">
        <strong STYLE="FONT-size:28px;">Just another blog</strong>
        <BR/><a href="account.php"><img src="img/back.png"/></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout"><img src="img/logout.png"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-body"> 
<h1 align="center">Categories</h1>

    <?php

while($userRow=$query->fetch_array()) {

$cid = $userRow['id'];
$subtotal = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE invid=$cid");
$total =  mysqli_num_rows($subtotal);

echo

 '<table width="100%" border="0" style="color:#fff;border: 5px #fff solid;margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" align="center" valign="top">
    <img src="inventory/' . $userRow['file'] . '" width="100" height="200" /></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
    <a href="viewitems.php?id='. $userRow['id'] . '"><h2 style="line-height:10px;">' . $userRow['name'] . '</h2> </a>   
    <strong>Category Name:</strong> ' . $userRow['name'] . '
    <br>
    <strong>Totalitems:</strong> ' . $total  . '    
        </td>

</table>';
}
?>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

now im getting this error

```
mysqli::query(): couldn't fetch mysqli
```

can someone pls help me?

Thank you

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close the database connection after the query from table1 on the line `$DBcon->close();`, and later try to call it again with `$subtotal = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE invid=$cid");`

Move that line to where you're done with database queries and you should be fine.

As a sidenote, you might want to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and use COUNT() to return the number of rows matching your second query.